# Ubuntu desktop 16.04 won't recognize images from Iphone 5s

Tags: 16.04, iphone

Ubuntu desktop 16.04 won't recognize images from iPhone 5s

My installation is fresh. Installed no foreign software.

I connect my iPhone. The iPhone itself is recognized, but there are no way to access the images.

As far as I know it should work just fine directly (the images are recognized in Windows 10).

Comment: Ever since Ubuntu started supporting to "mount" iOS devices in 10.04, every new iOS update would break this support. You have some options here: downgrade your iOS version to the one that previously was released before 16.04, install the most recent Ubuntu release and evenso hold the iOS update until a new Ubuntu is released or simply use a Windows install(virtual or real).

Comment: Eveso hold version?

Comment: Hold version, don't update iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of inherent discrapencies between versions (iOS and Ubuntu) the solution I used in the end for transffering mass amounts of images was using the [Google photos](https://www.google.com/photos/about/) service.

Instead of sending small amounts of images to email each time, I just backed them up from my phone with Google phtoos and then downloaded them in Ubuntu.